# hide and show angular ui boostrap popover when user enters password less than 8

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to show the UI Bootstrap popover when the user enters an invalid password.Here is my code.but it doesn't show popover.it I look at the log it triggers the showChat and hideChat events.but the popover doesn't display.Can someone help to resolve this issue?

HTML:

```
<a href="" id="popoverpassword" class="fa icon-iml-info"
    popover-placement="left" 
    audiochat-popover
    popover="ddssvssvs"
    popover-title="sdvsvsvvvdsvs"
    popover-trigger="showChat"
    ></a>
    <input ng-model="password" ng-change="vCharCount(password)">
```

Javascript:

```
angular.module('testpopover', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.config(['$tooltipProvider', function($tooltipProvider){
    $tooltipProvider.setTriggers({
        'showChat': 'hideChat'
    });
}])    
.directive('audiochatPopover', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) { 
            scope.$watch('showPopover', function() {
                if(scope.showPopover) {
                  console.log('trigger showChat')
                    element.get(0).dispatchEvent(new Event("showChat"));
                } else {
                   console.log('trigger hideChat')
                    element.get(0).dispatchEvent(new Event("hideChat"));
                }
            });
        }
    };
})
.controller('RoomController', function($scope) {
    $scope.showPopover = false;


     $scope.vCharCount = function() {
            if ($scope.password !=="" && $scope.password.length >= 8) {

                $scope.showPopover = false;
                return false;
            }else{

               $scope.showPopover=true

               return true;
            }
        };  
});
```

Comment: Which version of **UI Boostrap** are you using ? Because in the latest versions it's no more `$tooltipProvider` but `$uibTooltipProvider`

Comment: And you want the popover triggered whenever the password is incorrect or only when the user click on a button to validate his password ?

Comment: did you try `tooltip-is-open` flag to be pass to `uib-tooltip` directive element.? Something like [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/i6rHnWgWmpa0abZi5mly?p=preview)

Comment: @JeanJacques tooltipProvider is the supported one.popup should be triggered whenever password invalid.

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('demoModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);

angular.module('demoModule').config(function ($uibTooltipProvider) {

});

angular.module('demoModule').controller('PopoverDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {


     $scope.passValid = function() {
            if ((   $scope.isNumber()    &&
            $scope.isCharCount()) || !$scope.password) {


                return true;
            } else {


                return false;
            }
        };



    $scope.isCharCount = function() {
            if ($scope.password !=="" && $scope.password.length <= 8) {


                return true;
            }else{



               return false;
            }
        };

     $scope.isNumber = function() {
            var matches = $scope.password ? $scope.password.match(/\d+/g) : undefined;
            if (matches !== null) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        };


});
```

html:

```
<body ng-controller="PopoverDemoCtrl">


   <input type="text" ng-change="vCharCount(password)" ng-model="password"/>


  <i class="fa fa-link add-link" popover-placement="right" uib-popover-template="'password-pop'" popover-is-open="!passValid()" popover-title="New link"></i>


  <script type="text/ng-template" id="password-pop.html">
    <h1>Invalid Password</h1>

  </script>
```